# Consuming a Ruby on Rails app on my domain server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-phone-7, webserver

I am running rails version 2.3.2 on my website domain and I am having a huge problem with wrapping my head around how this works:

I have my website running a RoR app on my domain development server. It is just a sample scaffold that allows you to type in your name, zip, state, etc. I am using ruby 1.8.2, and have a mysql server also.

I want to consume this data into my windows phone 7 through SOAP (I don't know if I even have one to begin with), but here is where I have problems.

In using visual studio, it cannot locate my server when i direct it over to my url. It gives the error saying that there was nothing in the correct format.

Maybe I don't have a server running? I want to have the data be parsed out into XML for the phone to consume, but I have no idea how to set this up!

Basically, I have the domain, and the phone, but no knowledge of the steps inbetween.

Can anyone help me get this up and running?

Comment: 1.8.2 is pretty out-of-dated, better do not to use it.

Comment: can you use Rails 3? are you sure about SOAP, maybe REST?

Comment: are you sure about XML, probably JSON?

Comment: Umm, thanks I guess? It was what the web domain had in cpanel, and I decided to use it.

Comment: Please upgrade both rails and ruby versions, or just don't give out the website domain to anyone if you don't want to find yourself 'hacked'.

Comment: How would I go about upgrading them for my webdomain then?

Comment: that might be tricky. See if your hosting provider has any other rails options or if they'll allow you to upgrade it somehow. If not, find another hosting service :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:

First - have you actually started the server? eg by running "script/server" ?
You can test that the server is up and running by using "curl" (google for it to install/download" which is a very simple (and very commonly used) application for testing this stuff easily.

if you run curl and type in the url that you'd be accessing via your windows phone... and it responds with something (probably html), then the server is up and running. You can later use CURL to test if it responds to an xml request too.

Second: go look in the controller. See if it has a section such as:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.xml { render :xml => @widgets.to_xml }
end
```

it's the "respond_to" and "xml" bits that matter if you are going to get your system to consume xml. They should be present in every action in your controller. If not - you will have to go a research how to do this for your code - alternatively, using a later version of rails will let you use the up-to-date scaffold generators that should include these as standard.

Third: it is possible that your Windows phone app is just not requesting the resources in xml format and so Rails is returning html (which your SOAP parser won't understand). I don't know how you can check this, but what rails requires is for the HTML-header: "Accept" to be set to "application/xml" or "text/xml"

You can also test this for any given URL with curl by using eg: "curl -H 'Accept: text/xml' 127.0.0.1/myapp" - if it continues to spit out html (and not xml) then obviously it's not producing xml for that URL.

Comment: I think my problem was definitely in the controller, as I didn't even have that code.

Comment: Okey dokey - well, probably the quickest win for you would be to upgrade rails and re-run the generators. If you installed rails through rubygems then you should be able to just run "gem install rails -v 2.3.8" That will upgrade to v 2.3.8 - which isn't too far away from what you've got (ie you don't need to go all the way to 3.0)... then re-run the generators the same way you did this time... and you should get better code.

Comment: In terms of updating my ruby and rails, what if I just had the app on my subdomain but make it hidden and unable to be edited by anyone else? Would I still be able to pull the list I update and feed it to the phone, or would the phone, after say doing this, ask for authentication every time it tried to parse the feed?

Comment: Rails will ask for authentication with every request (web servers are stateless and do not retain knowledge this way). There are installable authentication gems tat are very good - but will require some work to get them running. Alternatively you can just use .htaccess files and if your windows phone can then "store your login" (just like a browser does), then it shouldn't be too arduous.

Comment: Oh - and in case you wondered... I would strongly recommend against just having a hidden server and hoping nobody will find it. Malware regularly trolls for random server ids and pings every port in the hope of finding such treasure... :(

Comment: You're my hero Tayrn. May I ask one more question for you? Since I want to use dreamweaver to upload my website, and for the ruby application to simply retrieve the HTML of the picture location, to throw into the phone for people to see the pictures.. How is it possible for me to be the sole person adding the html and ensuring that no one else can?

Comment: google/Read up on how to use .htaccess with rails. It's not the recommended way of securing your app, but it's probably the quickest to implement if it's *just* you going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this is to simply emit JSON and consume that on your mobile application. Generally you just need to call `.to_json` on an object and you're half done. SOAP requires a ton of XML overhead that's usually not worth it unless you're already neck-deep in an enterprise application that's overflowing with it.

Updating your Rails stack to 2.3.11 and Ruby 1.8.7 is *strongly* encouraged as older versions of Rails, as with any application, have vulnerabilities. Ruby 1.8.2 is from around 2005 and is effectively ancient.

Comment: To both Tadman and Taryn, thank you for a breadth of clarity. I will contact my domain provider and hope that I can gain some support with them regarding an upgrade.